# Displace Mesh along Curve on single axis

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

I am modeling bridges and want to use a curve to shape them. However I only want the vertices to move along a single axis (like Z).

[image: bridge]

With the Curve Modifier, the panels don't hang straight downwards.

Answer (score 4):

- Create a constant-offset array of a single mesh edge, crossways to the bridge-curve..
- Set the arrayed edge's duplication to Dupliverts
- Parent the vertical elements to the array of edges?

[image]

This might not suit .. there are other options, particles on placeholder planes, parenting with constraints..

Comment: It's a shame DupliFrames have gone.. they might have been a 'hack', but they were very handy for this sort of thing...